# Oscillating Electric Field and Dielectric Constant

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dielectric

Here's an extract from Purcell's Electricity and Magnetism:

> Every dielectric constant in the table is larger than 1. We should
>   expect that if our explanation is correct. The presence of a dielectric
>   could reduce the capacitance below that of the empty capacitor only if
>   its electrons moved, when the electric field was applied, in a direction
>   opposite to the resulting force. **For oscillating electric fields, by the way,
>   some such behaviour would not be absurd.** But for the steady fields we are
>   considering here it can’t work that way.

What does that mean? Does it imply that the dielectric constant of a material can be a function of externally applied field?

Please explain this in detail, such discussions aren't part of our course, but I am interested to know more about this unexpected phenomenon!

Comment: [Related on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility#Dispersion_and_causality). In particular, the dielectric constant depends on the frequency of the excitation, and can be less than 1 when there is a resonant behavior in the material. (Unfortunately I don't have any $\varepsilon(\omega)$ curve for a specific material to demonstrate this).